# SQL top with same price

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to make a query that will select the rows with minimum price, also if there are rows with the same min price they should be shown... My input till now

```
SELECT EB.RealEstateType,EB.Architecture,EB.Area,Price
FROM Rents AS R
INNER JOIN EstatesBasicInfo AS EB
ON EB.RealEstateID=R.RealEstateID
ORDER BY Price

Output

FirstColumnText|SecondColumnText|ThirdColumnText|   800,00

FirstColumnText|SecondColumnText|ThirdColumnText|   800,00

FirstColumnText|SecondColumnText|ThirdColumnText|   1500,00

FirstColumnText|SecondColumnText|ThirdColumnText|   5000,00
```

So for example with this data I want the top 2 to be shown... but i won't always know the amount of minimum duplicates(with the same price)... Thats why i can't use TOP 2 like now... Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the window function DENSE_RANK() to get ALL ties

```
Select RealEstateType,Architecture,Area,Price
 From  (
        SELECT EB.RealEstateType,EB.Architecture,EB.Area,Price
                ,DR = DENSE_RANK() over (Order By Price)
        FROM Rents AS R
        INNER JOIN EstatesBasicInfo AS EB
        ON EB.RealEstateID=R.RealEstateID
       ) A
Where DR=1
```

Comment: hm i thought of an other method while waiting for an answer    SELECT EB.RealEstateType,EB.Architecture,EB.Area,Price
FROM Rents AS R
INNER JOIN EstatesBasicInfo AS EB
ON EB.RealEstateID=R.RealEstateID
WHERE Price=(SELECT TOP 1 Price
FROM Rents AS R
INNER JOIN EstatesBasicInfo AS EB
ON EB.RealEstateID=R.RealEstateID
ORDER BY Price)

Comment: @MitkoZ Before we had the window functions, that would have been my choice as well.

Comment: @MitkoZ Like chicken soup for a cold... Couldn't hurt to try.  :)

Comment: btw i am getting some errors using your method Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The multi-part identifier "EB.RealEstateType" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The multi-part identifier "EB.Architecture" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The multi-part identifier "EB.Area" could not be bound.

Comment: @MitkoZ The nice feature of Dense_Rank() is that you are not limited to to just 1 value.  You could top 2 and bottom 2 with an additional Dense_Rank()

Answer (score 0):

You can use sub query

```
SELECT EB.RealEstateType,EB.Architecture,EB.Area
FROM Rents AS R
INNER JOIN EstatesBasicInfo AS EB
ON EB.RealEstateID=R.RealEstateID
WHERE Price = (
                Select min(price)
                FROM Rents AS R
                INNER JOIN EstatesBasicInfo AS EB
                ON EB.RealEstateID=R.RealEstateID
              )
```

But I would suggest to just do extra programming instead of this SQL.